# web service endpoint wrong address

Tags: c#

```
<services>
    <service name="WebServices.Service" behaviorConfiguration="WebServices.ServiceBehavior">
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <endpoint address="http://ip/Service.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WebServices.IService">
            <identity>
               <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
</services>
```

but my endpoint is still

svcutil.exe http://server-iis/Service.svc?wsdl. How to change `server-iis` to my IP?

Comment: Can you confirm that you changed correct config file?

Comment: 89.212.252.73 is your iis server address?

Comment: 89.212.252.73 is my test IIS server

Comment: wait a minute, do you want to just change address in the message that tells to use svcutil to generate code?

Comment: yes this mail: svcutil.exe http://server-iis/Service.svc?wsdl. Look here: http://89.212.252.73/Service.svc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try solution suggested in [here](http://computermutt.wordpress.com/2009/05/11/configuring-iis7-to-provide-correct-hostname-in-wcf-wsdl-and-service-metadata/).

I'am not sure but I hope this suggestion helps you.